# What do the shrines do and how do I get them for my cellar?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

I know that in hearthfire, you can get shrines for the cellar, but what do they do and how do I get them?

Answer (score 6):

Shrines can be found all over the skyrim,each shrine belongs to certain Aedra(they are something like gods in skyrim).

Once you activate a shrine you will be **cured of all curses** and get a **blessing**(passive bonus) that lasts for 8 hours or until you activate another shrine.

Bonuses are as follows :

- Shrine of Akatosh *-gives-* Regenerate Magicka, 10 pts for 8 hours
- Shrine of Arkay *-gives-* Fortify Health, 25 pts for 8 hours
- Shrine of Auriel(Dawnguard expansion) *-gives-* Fortify Marksman, 10 pts for 12 hours
- Shrine of Dibella *-gives-* Fortify Persuasion, 10 pts for 8 hours
- Shrine of Julianos *-gives-* Fortify Magicka, 25 pts for 8 hours
- Shrine of Kynareth *-gives-* Fortify Stamina, 25 pts for 8 hours
- Shrine of Mara *-gives-* Fortify Restoration, 10 pts for 8 hours
- Shrine of Stendarr *-gives-* Fortify Blocking, 10 pts for 8 hours
- Shrine of Talos *-gives-* Fortify Shouts, 0.2 pts for 8 hours
- Shrine of Zenithar *-gives-* Fortify Barter, 10 pts for 8 hours

With hearthfire expansion you can make altar in the basement of your house using the crafting table.You can then add all the listed shrines on your newly built altar by crafting them using crafting table in basement.

See [here](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Shrines) for required materials and exact locations of shrines.

Also you can find all those shrines at one place in the **Temple of the Divines in Solitude**.Shrine of Talos will be unavailable there until you take over Solitude with Stormcloaks.

Comment: One thing that wasn't mentioned is that you have to have an amulet to build them, I didn't look at the requirements for the shrine and lost my one that reduces time between shouts, lol

Answer (score 1):

Shrines can be crafted like any other piece of furniture in Hearthfire after you have built the cellar and an altar inside the cellar.